# Year Week format R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe (df_malaria) with many columns, two of them represent the year and the week of the case.

| Year | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 |
| 2010 | 4 |
| 2010 | 5 |
| 2010 | 6 |

What i would like to have is an additional column with the date displayed as Year - Week

| Year-week |
| --- |
| 2010 - 01 |
| 2010 - 04 |
| 2010 - 05 |
| 2010 - 06 |

I tried to achieve this using the code below but it didnt´t work.

```
df_malaria$date <- as.Date(with(df_malaria, paste(Year, Week, sep="-")), "%Y-%W")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `paste0(df$Year," - ",df$Week)`? Why is this not enough?

Comment: Doesn't work, I just get NAs

Comment: `unite(df,'Year-Week',  Year, Week, sep = '-', remove = FALSE)`

Comment: Why do you get `NA`? the code provided should work if you do exactly what is written. DO NOT USE `as.Date` function anywhere

Comment: Then it would be better for you to post a sample of your data, otherwise it will be hard for us to determine what is going on.

Comment: What's wrong with the as.Date function?

Comment: @JahiZamy because its not a valid date

Answer (score 0):

in base R:

```
transform(df,Year_Week= sprintf('%d - %02d',Year, Week))

  Year Week Year_Week
1 2010    1 2010 - 01
2 2010    4 2010 - 04
3 2010    5 2010 - 05
4 2010    6 2010 - 06
```

You can also use `unite` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
unite(df,'Year-Week',  Year, Week, sep = ' - ')

  Year-Week
1  2010 - 1
2  2010 - 4
3  2010 - 5
4  2010 - 6
```